# How do I bind JSON data to my class property

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to make a weather application that lists 5 cities and their current weather. When you click on a city it goes to a detail view which shows the 5 day forecast for the city.

Right now I have a weatherItem class:

```
export class WeatherItem {
  city: string;
  description: string;
  temperature: number;
}
```

*This is the method in my weatherService that gets the current weather information for the 5 cities:

```
fetchCurrent(){
    return Observable.forkJoin(
      this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chicago&units=imperial&appid=f630449a4407b742703bf37d8e8c9057').map(
      (response) => response.json()),
     this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Dallas&units=imperial&appid=f630449a4407b742703bf37d8e8c9057').map(
       (response) => response.json()),
     this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Milwaukee&units=imperial&appid=f630449a4407b742703bf37d8e8c9057').map(
       (response) => response.json()),
     this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Seattle&units=imperial&appid=f630449a4407b742703bf37d8e8c9057').map(
       (response) => response.json()),
     this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Washington&units=imperial&appid=f630449a4407b742703bf37d8e8c9057').map(
       (response) => response.json())
  );
  }
```

and this is the method I call in my WeatherComponent which uses the fetchCurrent() method from my weatherService

```
getWeather(): void {
   this.weatherService.fetchCurrent()
   .subscribe(data => this.weatherItems = data);
  }
```

it successfully grabs the current weather data from openweathermap.org but in my 
WeatherComponent I am currently displaying the data like this:

```html
<ul class="weatherItems">
    <li *ngFor="let weatherItem of weatherItems" class="box" (click)="gotoDetail(weatherItem)">
      <div class="col-1">
        <h3>{{weatherItem.name}}</h3>
        <p class="info">{{weatherItem.weather[0].description}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <span class="temperature">{{weatherItem.main.temp}}° F</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

How do I take that JSON data and map it to my view correctly? For example I had

> {{weatherItem.city}}

before when I was using mock data but now I have to use the JSON data and I can't get the view to display the city name correctly unless I use

> {{weatherItem.name}}

Is there a way in angular 2 to bind the "name" data from JSON to my weatherItem.city property?

Comment: what does data look like?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? And how are you receiving data and converting it to JSON?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console but I would like to display my data in the view template as {{weatherItem.city}} instead of {{weatherItem.name}} which is the JSON data property.

I just added the code snippet which calls http.get. That's how I'm currently receiving the data for my 5 cities.

Comment: The data currently shows the correct city name, temperature, and weather description for each city but only if I bind it to the view as shown in the html above

Answer (score 0):

First of all if your `WeatherItem` are just model of your backend class it should look like this (model class should have same property names as json):

```
export class WeatherItem {
  constructor(weather: Weather,
              base: string,
              id: number,
              name: string,
              cod: number) {}
}

export class Weather {
    constructor(id: number,
                main: string,
                description: string,
                icon: string){}
}
```

Second one, your `weatherItems` should be declared like that:

```
public weatherItems: Array<WeatherItem>; // or just weatherItem: Weather if your json just return single object
```

Of course you can create full model with rest of your json properties (main, wind, rain ect), but its not needed if you dont need to use it.